# Find the value of $\sqrt{(b-a-4)^2}- \sqrt{(a-b+1)^2}$ if a>0 and b<0

Tags: contest-math, problem-solving, roots, exponentiation

Find the value of $\sqrt{(b-a-4)^2}- \sqrt{(a-b+1)^2}$ if $a>0$ and $b<0$.

How do i find the value?  This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: What doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 4):

$$\because b-a-4<0 \text{ and that }a-b+1>0$$

\begin{align*}
\therefore \sqrt{(b-a-4)^2}-\sqrt{(a-b+1)^2}&=-(b-a-4)-(a-b+1)\\
&=-b+a+4-a+b-1\\
&=3
\end{align*}